# tmux only shows current pane title if queried from a key binding

Tags: tmux

Suppose have 3 panes in a tmux window: `vim`, `vom`, and `vam`

I want to access the pane title of the first pane as part of a keyboard mapping (forward command to vim if vim's in pane 1). It wasn't working as expected and I've narrowed it down to the following...

If I run:

```
tmux display-message "`tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_title}'`"
```

the result is:

```
vim
vom
vam
```

This is what I'd expect. If I try to run the same from a key mapping:

```
bind -n C-h run "tmux display-message \"`tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_title}'`\""
```

I get the title of the current pane repeated three times:

```
vom
vom
vom
```

Does `run-shell` execute in a different context or something?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `tmux list-keys` in the terminal and see what `C-h` gets mapped to. I get something like this:

```
bind-key        C-t run-shell "tmux display-message "name1
name2
name3""
```

From the above, you can see the backtick interpolation happens at the moment **when the key is bound**, not later when the binding is **executed**.

I don't know how to get around this and you must be having a lot of pain because of so many nested commands.

Personally, when hacking tmux I always apply the rule of "get to the shell as soon as possible".
For your example that would mean:

1. keep the key binding simple: `bind -n C-h run "/path/to/script.sh"`
2. create a script, make it executable and put the rest of what you want to do in it. This would be its content:

   ```
   tmux display-message "`tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_title}'\`"
   ```

I just did it and it worked for me locally. Hope that helps!

Comment: Interestingly, `list-keys` didn't show me that output (running 1.9a). Splitting my logic out into a script _did_ fix my problem though, so thanks!